# RESTful API call not updating local array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a factory service that gets data from the back, and I'm trying to populate a local array like so:

```
(function() {
app.controller('UpdateProvidersCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngDialog', '$http', 'Provider', '$resource', '$window','SpecialtyService', function($scope, ngDialog, $http, Provider, $resource, $window,SpecialtyService) {
var specialties = [];
SpecialtyService.getService().then(function(data){
   $scope.specialty = data;
    angular.forEach(data.specialty, function(item){
       specialties.push(item);
    );
 });

    console.log(specialties);
```

the console.log returns an empty array, and i know for a fact that the data is being retrieved because i've placed other console.log messages and the promise is returning an array.

this is my service

```
app.factory('SpecialtyService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  function SpecialtyService() {
    this.service = $resource('/api/specialty_search'); 
  };

  SpecialtyService.prototype.getService = function() {
    return this.service.get().$promise;
  };

  return new SpecialtyService;
}]);
```

Is it returning empty because of the asynchronous call? or am i doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function() {
app.controller('UpdateProvidersCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngDialog', '$http', 'Provider', '$resource', '$window','SpecialtyService', function($scope, ngDialog, $http, Provider, $resource, $window,SpecialtyService) {
var specialties = [];
SpecialtyService.getService().then(function(data){
   $scope.specialty = data;
    angular.forEach(data.specialty, function(item){
       specialties.push(item);
    );
   console.log(specialties);
 });
```

Since your service call is async you need to add your console.log in the correct place(callback).